# the detailed calculation method and process of the adjusted rand score

Tags: python

python programming, need to use metrics.adjusted_rand_score to measure  the similarity between two data clusterings, however, have not understand the detailed principle of adjusted_rand_score(rand index), how to calculate it, according to the definition of rand index from internet, it is: The Rand Index computes a similarity measure between two clusterings by considering all pairs of samples and counting pairs that are assigned in the same or different clusters in the predicted and true clusterings.
 for example:

```
>>> adjusted_rand_score([0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1])  
0.57...

>>> adjusted_rand_score([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2])  
0.57...

>>> adjusted_rand_score([0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3])
0.0

>>> labels_true = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
>>> labels_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]

>>> metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels_pred)  
0.24
```

how to get the value : 0.57 and 0.0, 0.24, could you please tell me the detailed calculation method and process

Answer (score 1):

Consider the first example:

```
>>> adjusted_rand_score([0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1])  
0.57...
```

According to Adjusted Rand index explained in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) page, you have to make a 3x2 contingency table (you have 3 clusters in the first partition and 2 clusters in the second partition). So we have:

```
n11 = 2
n12 = 0
n13 = 0
n21 = 0
n22 = 1
n23 = 1
```

and

```
a1 = 2
a2 = 2
b1 = 2
b2 = 1
b3 = 1
```

According to the ARI formula in [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index)

```
ARI = {1 - [(1+1)*1)/6]} / {[ 1/2 * [(1+1)+1] ] - 1/3}= 4/7 = 0.57
```